# youtube embed autoplay on page anchor link click

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube, embed

I have a youtube clip embedded at the bottom of a page, with an anchor link at the top that scrolls to it when clicked.

Is it possible to autoplay the embedded youtube clip when the anchor link is clicked?

Could I use jQuery to do some kind of on click function of the anchor link, autoplay youtube embed?

Any pointers are highly appreciated!
Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the youtube API to do this. Here is a plunker to demonstrate: http://plnkr.co/edit/lYCJeQBj0Cjl0FuzKTfE?p=preview

```
var player;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  //this is the id of your video
  player = new YT.Player('your-video');
}
//call this function from your links onclick
function playVideo() {
  if(player) {
    player.playVideo();
  }
}
//this loads the youtube api
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);


//iframe embed markup, note the enablejsapi=1 portion of the video URL
<iframe 
   id="your-video" 
   width="420" 
   height="315" 
   src="//www.youtube.com/embed/6yEgcb167k4?enablejsapi=1" 
   frameborder="0" 
   allowfullscreen
>
</iframe>

//your button markup
<a href="#your-video" onclick="playVideo()">Go to video</a>
```

Comment: Wow thank you for the quick response! I didn't realize it would require using a youtube API. I am going to try and plug this into my page! Very much appreciated thank you!!!

Comment: One thing you need to make sure you do is add ?enablejsapi=1 parameter to the video URL in the iframe embed code.

Comment: OK cool so I would add that where it says ('your-video') correct? Do i need to include a <script> call to the youtube api?

Comment: If you have a look at the html in the link I sent you it should be a little more clear. You can actually download the source and view it on your computer. I also updated the code in the sample above.

The script I posted above adds the script tag for the youtube api dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Easier way to play youtube videos -

```
$("iframe")[0].contentWindow.postMessage("{\"event\":\"command\",\"func\":\"playVideo\",\"args\":\"\"}", "*");
```

Make sure that the iframe has loaded `$(window).load(function () {` and to add `&amp;enablejsapi=1` to the url.